# How to sample vectors close to the minimum eigenvector of a unitary matrix?

Tags: mathematics, unitarity

Say that we have an ***unknown*** $2^{n}\times2^{n}$ unitary matrix $U$ with  eigenvectors $|v_{i}\rangle$ and eigenvalues $e^{2\pi j \theta_{i}}$and we want to sample a vector, say $|\phi \rangle$. Since the eigenvectors of $U$ form an orthonormal basis, $|\phi \rangle$ can be written as
$$ |\phi \rangle = \sum_{i} \alpha_{i}|v_{i} \rangle,$$
where $|\alpha_{i}|^{2}$ is the probability of $|\phi \rangle$ collapsing to any of the eigenvector states $|v_{i}\rangle$.

Let us assume that there is no degeneracy and there exists some minimum eigenvalue $\theta_{k}$ with the associated eigenvector $|v_{k}\rangle$. What I want to know is whether there is a way to sample $|\phi \rangle$ such that amongst all the eigenvectors $|v_{i}\rangle$, it is closest to $|v_{k}\rangle$. In other words, $|\phi \rangle$ is such that -
$$ | \langle v_{k}|\phi\rangle|^{2} > | \langle v_{i}|\phi\rangle|^{2},\qquad \forall\ i \neq k.$$

Comment: I assume you're taking $0\leq\theta_i<1$?
Also, I'm a little confused - is $|\phi\rangle$ given to you (i.e. are the $\alpha_i$ fixed)? Or is your question how to construct the $|\phi\rangle$ in such a way as to maximise $|\alpha_k|^2$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the question. I want to construct the $|\phi \rangle$ state in such a way so as to maximise $|\alpha_{k}|^{2}$. Also, $\theta_{i}$ does belong to the domain [0,1).

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the rules of the game. Can you give a sketch of what you expect such a sampling procedure to look like?

Comment: Do we have to make use only of $U$, or might we be able to use controlled-$U$?

Comment: For a better context, think of the QPE algorithm but with no eigenvectors. I want to provide a good initial estimate of the eigenvector of the "unknown" unitary and I 'have' the ability to use controlled U gate. So my question is that how can that initial vector be given as an input such that is overlap is biggest to the eigenvector associated with the minimum eigenvalue.

Comment: I suspect that this may be impossible based on your definition of "minimum". Here's a vague argument. Suppose you have a unitary $U$ that has a min eigenvalue $e^{2 \epsilon \pi i}$ for some small $\epsilon > 0$. Then define a unitary $U'$ which is the same as $U$ except you perturb this min eigenvalue to $e^{2 (\epsilon - \delta) \pi i}$ with $\delta>0$. This new unitary should be close to $U$ if $\delta$ or $\epsilon$ are small  but if $\delta > \epsilon$ then suddenly this eigenvalue is very large by your definition. Thus your algorithm wont work continuously on the space of unitaries $U$.

Comment: Thank you @Rammus. I would think more then, for defining a better initial state.

Answer (score 1):

I am creating an instance of your generic problem:

1. If we consider $n=1$ then $Z$ Gate will become your $2^n \times 2^n$ "unknown" unitary matrix $U$.
2. Then $\vert 0 \rangle$ and $\vert 1\rangle$ will be its eigenvectors and $1$ and $-1$ the corresponding eigenvalues.
3. Now $\vert \phi\rangle$ is a vector which can be represented as a linear combination of given eigenvectors $\vert 0 \rangle$ and $\vert 1\rangle$.
4. In this scenario, $\vert 1\rangle$ is the eigenvector associated with minimum eigenvalue of $-1$.

Let us select one of the eigenvector at random, such as $\vert 1\rangle$.
Now you want to say that the system is in state $\vert \phi\rangle$ and it's measurement is always closer to $\vert 1 \rangle$ than to $\vert 0\rangle$
i.e. $\vert \langle 1 \vert \phi \rangle\vert^2 > \vert \langle 0 \vert \phi \rangle\vert^2$

Given an eigenvector $\vert V_k\rangle$, you want a formal way to find a $\vert \phi \rangle$ state which is closer to $\vert V_k \rangle$.
i.e. in this case, find $\vert \phi \rangle$ which is closer to $\vert 1 \rangle$.

If I have understood the problem properly then I recommend following approach:

$$
\vert \langle V_k \vert \phi \rangle \vert^2 > \vert \langle V_i \vert \phi \rangle \vert^2, \forall i \neq k
$$
$$
\vert \phi \rangle = \sum_{i} a_i \vert V_i \rangle = a_k \vert V_k \rangle + \sum_{i \neq k} a_i \vert V_i \rangle
$$
$$
\vert a_k \vert ^2 > \sum_{i \neq k} \vert a_i \vert^2
$$

You need to select a state $\vert \phi \rangle$ such that probability of selected eigenvector is greater than sum total of all other states in its wavefunction.

Comment: Well Sachin thanks for the answer. You understood the question correctly but I'd like to ask 2 things.First, how can we say that a single qubit matrix boils down to just a Z-gate. Second, since the matrix is 'unknown',as is in the case of QPE,we do not have the knowledge of the eigenvectors of U, so I am not sure if we can "select" eigenvectors.

Comment: I have considered Z-gates for illustration purpose only. If we provide superposition of eigenstates to QPE then we will obtain corresponding superposition of related eigenphases.